# Очередность выполнения анимации элементов

Tags: jquery

Добрый день, можно ли в jQuery задать поочередность выполнения анимации для разных элементов?

Гугл говорит, что это без проблем делается для одного элемента, а мне для разных нужно.

```
$("#my-div-1").animate({height: "hide"}, 1000);
$("#my-div-2").animate({height: "show"}, 1000);
```

Например, вот тут, чтобы сначала блок **`my-div-1`** спрятался за 1000мс, а сразу после этого блок **`my-div-2`** показался.

У кого-то какие-то идеи есть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#my-div-1").animate({height: "hide"}, 1000, function(){
    $("#my-div-2").animate({height: "show"}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: туплю сегодня неймоверно, ты уже второй раз выручаешь :)
спасибо!